# Не получается прочитать из файла значения

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, не получается прочитать из файла 8 значений (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream f ("file.txt");
    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        int a;
        f >> a;
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод консоли:

> 2665544 
> 2665544 
> 2665544 
> 2665544
> 2665544
> 2665544
> 2665544
> 2665544

ВЫПОЛНИТЬ `SUCCESSFUL` (общее время: 136мс)

Работаю в NetBeans. Сам файл лежит в папке с проектом.

Что я делаю не так?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все указывает на то, что файл таки не открылся - на него не хватило прав или он он лежит не в одной с выполняемой программой директории. 2665544 - значения неинициализированой переменной a.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream f ("file.txt");
    if (!f)
    {
        cerr <<"Error open file!"<<endl;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        int a = -13666;
        f >> a;
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

пробуем так, будет видно. Потом пробуем `ifstream f ("Полный путь до файла>");`

Comment: файл действительно не открывается.
и полный путь до файла не помогает

Comment: как путь до файла выглядит? Некоторые редакторы к стати, запрещают доступ к открытым файлам, может поэтому?

Comment: C:\\file.txt
 и еще по всякому пробовал типа:
C:\file.txt
C:/file.txt
C://file.txt

я пару месяцев назад, когда курсовую писал, считывал и записывал в файл, но пользуясь другими операторами, какими уже не помню. Все в том же нетбинсе

Comment: Правильно будет "C:\\file.txt" или "С:/file.txt". А как там с правами на чтение?

Comment: с правами все окей

в общем пересел на линукс, там все ок)

Comment: Кардинальное решение =)
"C:\\file.txt" конечно же.

Comment: "C:<ДВА ПРЯМЫХ СЛЕША!!!!111>file.txt"